# Ubuntu 16.04 Python Version Management Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, word-cloud

I have Python3.5 and Python3.6 installed on Ubuntu 16.04.  I have installed pip for 3.6 and am using 3.6 for development.  I tried to install a package (wordcloud) in 3.6 and it appeared to install correctly but I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/mnt/data/projects/CSC594/HW01/CSC594-DMARKS-HW01-WordCloud.py", line 11, in <module>
  import wordcloud as wc
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/wordcloud/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  from .wordcloud import (WordCloud, STOPWORDS, random_color_func,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/wordcloud/wordcloud.py", line 19, in <module>
  from PIL import Image
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 66, in <module>
  from PIL import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging'
```

I am not sure what is happening but, python3 is a symbolic link to python3.5 yet when I execute the code, I am calling it in python3.6.  Everything looks fine except when it calls the PIL package.  PIL is actually installed in 3.6, but not 3.5.

I don't understand why it switches from:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
```

to:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

Why does this happen and how do I resolve this situation?

Comment: What does `import sys; print(sys.path)` display in the two versions?

Comment: Python3: ['', '/usr/lib/python35.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']

Comment: Python3.6: ['', '/usr/local/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages']

Comment: I'm not sure how it was even finding `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages` when that's not in `sys.path`, only `site-packages`. I thought the way Debian/Ubuntu handled `dist-packages` was a custom `site.py` file that added it to the `sys.path` at startup, and suspected something weird was going on there… but apparently I'm completely out of date on this, and therefore can't help you. (You may want to look at their current `site.py` file yourself—`import site; print(site.__file__)` if you don't know where to find it—and see if you can work it out, though.)

Comment: Anyway, last time I looked, their `site.py` always adds `/usr/local/lib/python{X}.{Y}/dist-packages` and `/usr/lib/python{X}.{Y}/dist-packages`, but only adds `/usr/lib/python{X}/dist-packages` when it can determine it's the "system Python", which is the part I thought might be going wrong, if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot see anything out of place with this.  Are there any other places that python keeps pointers between environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trusty offers a 3.5 setup, and that won't change. It may be possible to have the two coexist in the way you suggest, but you are finding it challenging. Recommend deleting your python3.6. (Or switching to an ubuntu based on 3.6.)

Install [miniconda3](https://conda.io/miniconda.html), and use that to provide python3.6, PIL, and friends. Very clean. You'll be glad you did.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I did and now My code works.